# Using CELL with ROW, INDEX, and MATCH Functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm working on trying to display the contents of a cell if data in the same row meets a certain criteria. In the case I am currently working on, if a value in a column is a maximum value I want to display the contents of that cell that is in the same row but different column.

My existing code is shown below:

```
=CELL("contents","B" & ROW(INDEX(E3:E75,MATCH(MAX(E3:E75),E3:E75,0)))
```

I know the `"B" & ROW(INDEX(E3:E75,MATCH(MAX(E3:E75),E3:E75,0)))` works as I have tried it in a different cell and it gives me the output I expected which was a string "B#". My issue is I can't seem to do anything useful with it, as its not acting as a cell input in formulas. I'm not quite sure what my issue is, but I would assume it has to do with syntax of how I'm inputting the data into the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the correct range in the INDEX and skip all the other work:

```
=INDEX(B3:B75,MATCH(MAX(E3:E75),E3:E75,0))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question, is there a way to find the "next" max, or if its too complicated I can ask another question.

Comment: You would use LARGE() instead of Max which allows you to dictate which one you want(1st,2nd,...)